# Facebook “Activity Feed” on Blogger

Tags: facebook, blogger

Facebook "Activity Feed" plugin, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/, requires you to enter the domain. The blogger URLs are usually in this format: http://abcxyz.blogspot.com. So what can I use as the domain? If I use "abcxyz.blogspot.com" as domain, it does not display anything. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'abcxyz.blogspot.com' is correct from readin the info on that page. Are you sure there is data that can be shown in the plugin? Maybe there just isn't any activity yet?

Comment: On my blog I have Facebook "Like" plugin on the side banner. On each blog post, I also have Facebook comment box, Like button and Send button. All these are perfectly doing their jobs.